# Displaying an image without cropping or stretching etc with max-height

Tags: html, css

I have an image (of which I don't precisely know the width / height --> loaded from database), which should stretch to the full container-width (see rounded corners). This I solved quite nicely. But especially with portrait images, they sometimes get too large, therefore I would like to apply a max-height. How can I do this?

Current code without a max-height (works great otherwise)

```css
.avatar-box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.avatar-thumb-square2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.avatar-thumb-square2 .avatar-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar-box" data-controller="responsive-image">
  <div class="avatar-thumb-square2">
    <img class="avatar-image" src="https://www.alten.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/satellite-donnees-oceanographiques.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

This results in something like this:
[image]

But as you can see, the image is too large vertically, therefore I would like to apply a max-height. How can I limit the image size to grow to a max of 400px for example. By just applying a max-height, the image gets cropped. See sample

[image]

So how can I show the full image (center it if it doesn't stretch 100%) and keep the rounded corners? I'm okay to use JavaScript.

Comment: You don't need any of those vendor prefixes unless you're supporting IE8.

Comment: also you dont ened to absolutely position your image, it would be easier if you just using `object-fit`-property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.avatar-thumb-square2 .avatar-image {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.avatar-thumb-square2{
    width:30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar-box" data-controller="responsive-image">
  <div class="avatar-thumb-square2" data-responsive-image-target="wrapper">
    <img class="avatar-image" src="https://www.alten.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/satellite-donnees-oceanographiques.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think he's looking for `object-fit: contain` not `cover`.

Comment: This way part of the image is cut off too. And is there any way on how to make the image grow and shrink with the size of the parent div (hence no fixed width or height

Comment: I've changed the styles so now the image resizes horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's better to set a width and height to a div and have this class for the img tag :

```
<div class="container" >
  <img class="responsive" />
</div>
```

```
.container {
  width : 100% ;
  height : 200px ;
}

.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

So the image will fit itself inside the div container hope it helps .

Comment: You should copy the snippet down here and demonstrate your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a definite max-height and  you know you want the width to be no more than 100% then set the width: 100% (as you have now) and the height: whatever you want the maximum height to be and then use object-fit: contain.

The system will ensure the whole image is shown within those bounds, whatever the image aspect ratio might be.

```css
.avatar-box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.avatar-thumb-square2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.avatar-thumb-square2 .avatar-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh; /* for demo, whatever you want the max height to be */
  object-fit: contain; 
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar-box" data-controller="responsive-image">
  <div class="avatar-thumb-square2" data-responsive-image-target="wrapper" style="padding-bottom: 56%;">
    <img class="avatar-image" src="https://www.alten.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/satellite-donnees-oceanographiques.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should need to make sure image width and height fully cover parent area.So, I set `min-width:100%` and `min-height:100%` in image's class. And then I want to adjust parent `width` and `height` or `max-width` and `max-height`. I think it can work nicely.Please check in snippet.

```css
.avatar-box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* adjust parent height(max-height) or width*/
  max-height: 200px;
}

.avatar-thumb-square2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.avatar-thumb-square2 .avatar-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* Need to show full width and height */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar-box" data-controller="responsive-image">
  <div class="avatar-thumb-square2" data-responsive-image-target="wrapper" style="padding-bottom: 56%;">
    <img class="avatar-image" src="https://www.alten.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/satellite-donnees-oceanographiques.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But his way the image is completely cut off. The image and the parent with the rounded borders should shrink to the image size.